# How to eliminate high multicollinearity with a continuous moderating variable, and a categorical independent variable

Tags: categorical-data, multicollinearity

I am looking at whether Corporate Venture Capital-backed firms (1) perform better than Independent Venture capital - backed firms(0) in their POST-IPO performance. My assumption is that this relationship is either strengthened or weakened by the amount of Experience (continuous).

After creating a new variable for Corporate VC*Experience, I then put these values in a regression and it gives me a VIF of over 23.

Comment: Try centering the continuous variable, that often helps.

Answer (score 1):

*To elaborate on Peter Flom's point:*

People often centre moderator variables (i.e., subtract the mean from the variable) before forming the interaction term in order to reduce multicollinearity between the component moderator variables and the interaction term.

The step of centring will not change the r-square change you get in a hierarchical regression when including the interaction term in a discrete step, but it may make interpretation of the coefficients clearer.

Comment: So I can centre the moderator without having to do the same for the independent variable (dummy)?

Comment: You could centre the binary variable as well if you want. That should further reduce the multicollinearity. People often don't because binary variables coded zero one are easy to interpret.